# How to implement multiple Content-Security-Policies and headers?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, content-security-policy

I have an email related application where I want to block alerts in JavaScript through an attachment. For example, I have implemented following CSP header:

```
Header Set Content-Security-Policy "script-src http://192.168.0.1/trusted/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
```

By this policy alerts from external sources are blocked, but code like &ltscript>alert(123)&lt/script>' executes, if I send a HTML document as an attachment through the app. I cannot change the code and move all JavaScript code from HTML page to another '.js' file. It will be very time consuming process. 
Is there any way to solve this problem? If I implement multiple headers it leads to conflict.

Also I was thinking of using aliasing to allow trusted code from another ip like 192.168.0.2/trusted/ but will this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might display the HTML from attachments in a [sandboxed iframe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/). It has the following advantages:

- the sandbox itself reduces impact of any malicious code in the attachment,
- you can set a separate CSP header for the iframe URL and it will not impact the outer HTML, where you need to allow inline code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will test and try to implement 'sandboxed iframe'.